# Data type in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, type-conversion

i have this descriptions **Department Total 500**,when i declare the data type as Number or text it display an error message..What data type should i use?i have this options below

[image: ms access datatype]

Comment: **The Value you entered isn't valid for this field**..eg you may have entered text in a field or a number that is larger than the FieldSize setting permits..thats the error message

Comment: Did you enter the words "department total 500" in the number field?

Comment: i declare its as DeptDesc..and that "department total 500" i enter or slect from my combo box

Comment: If the combo box is bound to a field/column of type `number` then it won't accept letters.